# AWS cli - DynamoDb batch-execute-statement return Expected identifier for simple path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to initially update an item in a table by using the batch-execute-statement as the first try and when that succeeds , add more statements in the file that holds these statements.
As of now I have the following

```
[
  {
    "Statement": "UPDATE 'table_t268468eaf8b64c7b9d3eb2655e98ebd5' SET x=1678976403 WHERE Key='e1c09d48-fdc5-41eb-8ca2-f7b4ff8a01c5' and anotherColumn='e1c09d48-fdc5-41eb-8ca2-f7b4ff8a01c5'"
  }
]
```

But when running the following

```
aws dynamodb batch-execute-statement --statements file://batch-execute.json
```

I am always getting the following error

```
{
    "Responses": [
        {
            "Error": {
                "Code": "ValidationError",
                "Message": "Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed: Expected identifier for simple path"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea why ? From what I can see in other examples and documentation I have the right syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated my answer because of DynamoDB reserved word usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Key` attribute name in your query is actually a [DynamoDB reserved word](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) so you'll have to escape and quote it, for example:

```
SET \"Key\"='fred'
```

Also, I don't believe that single quotes are allowed with table names (at least they fail for me) so remove the quotes surrounding the table name, for example:

```
[
  {
    "Statement": "UPDATE table1 SET x=2 WHERE \"Key\"='3' and anotherColumn='4'"
  }
]
```

Alternatively, use escaped double-quotes around the table name, for example:

```
[
  {
    "Statement": "UPDATE \"table1\" SET x=2 WHERE \"Key\"='3' and anotherColumn='4'"
  }
]
```

Finally, ensure that your WHERE clause includes an equality test on all of the primary key attributes (partition key and optional sort key).

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Unfortunately the table name has a underscore and aws cli throws an error of unexpected keyword if I remove the single quotes. Also the value I am adding  in the key I am sure its unique as I filter the data from the aws management console and its only one.

Comment: It works for me with the awscli on Mac, exactly as you're using it. Both the unquoted table name and the escaped, double-quoted table name. My awscli version is aws-cli/2.9.17.

Comment: Also, I used the same table name of `table_t268468eaf8b64c7b9d3eb2655e98ebd5` in my tests.

Comment: I am using the latest awscli on Windows .  Its weird I agree , every time I try to escape the table name or remove the  quotes it throws the unexpected keyword and when having the single quotes in the table name I get the "Expected identifier for simple path" , even though with the same filtering from AWS management studio I get just one record. The table does not have a sort key only a partition key which I am using , but even if I add more columns with add , still the same.

Comment: Works correctly for me on Windows Server (EC2) with both unquoted and escaped, double-quoted table name. However, I was using key attribute names of `pk` and `sk`, not `Key` as you have, so my test wasn't 100% identical. After introducing an attribute named `Key`, I realized that it's a reserved word so needs to be quoted.